# getting name in firebase with flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-authentication

I am having a problem when I'm trying to learn flutter and firebase. I am trying to access the name of the Google Account but I cannot as the type are not compatible. `myHomePage` is just another page for my app.

This is the code segment that have a problem.

```
class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  User user ;

  void click() {
    signInWithGoogle().then((user) => {
      this.user = user as User,
      Navigator.push(context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage(this.user.displayName)))
    });
  }

  Widget googleLoginButton(){
    return OutlineButton(
        onPressed: this.click,
      shape : RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45)),
      splashColor: Colors.grey,
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
      child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Image(image: AssetImage('assets/google_logo.png'), height: 35),
          Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
              child: Text('Sign in with Google',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey,
                      fontSize: 25)))],
      ))

    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
                labelText: "Type your name : ",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(width: 5, color: Colors.black)),
                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.done),
                  splashColor: Colors.orange,
                  tooltip: "Submit",
                  onPressed: this.click,
                ),
              ),
            )));
  }
}
```

The error that it will show is this:

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'User'
```

I understand the type is not compatible but as you can see the code below (the main part of the error) :

```
class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
      User user ;
    
      void click() {
        signInWithGoogle().then((user) => {
          this.user = user as User,
          Navigator.push(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage(this.user.displayName)))
        });
      }
```

I tried a lot of times and find some other tutorial but I can't solve this problem.
The `user` in the `then` method after `signInWithGoogle` is a String where it contains the information of the user. I will like to ask how am I going to access the name of the Google Account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `signInWithGoogle()` function in the [FlutterFire example](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/social#google) returns a `UserCredential` future, which has a user property. Try:

```
signInWithGoogle().then((userCredential) => {
      this.user = userCredential.user;
      Navigator.push(context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage(this.user.displayName)))
    });
```

Comment: It cannot be done also. It has an error showing that `error: The getter 'user' isn't defined for the type 'String'.` after adding the `.user`. The `.user` is underlined with red wave line also.

Comment: After seeing the example you given I think I know what is the problem. My `auth.dart` the `signInWithGoogle` returns a Future<String>, that's why it has a problem. After I change it to Future<User> the problem is solved. Thanks!!